# Pods-Framework with multisite

Tags: wordpress, pods-framework

I have a wordpress multisite. But I tried to find a **recipe** or **tutorial** on how to create a multisite-pod. There is none! Not a single example.

Could someone post an example please? How to use a pod within a template.php?

The structure of my domains/mapping:

**example.org**

- network.example.org // define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'network.example.org');
- example.org
- example.de

The necessary fields are: **name, content, link(german), link(english)**